# Javascript get item in object code

Tags: javascript

So I have some Javascript code that resembles the following:

```
var mylibrary = new (function ()
{

    this._getLibraryObj = function ()
    {
        var newLibraryObj = {};
        var libraryData = window.specifiedLibraryData;
        // Add head librarian details
        // open library
        // etc. etc. turn into an object from data

        return newLibraryObj ;
    };

    this.item = function (item)
    {

        if (this.obj && item in this.obj)
        {
            return this.obj[item];
        }
        else
        {
            this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();
            if (item in this.obj)
            {
                return this.obj[item];
            }
            return null;
        }
    };

    return this;
})();
```

What annoys me is that `this.item(item)` function repeats the `item in this.obj[item]` and I find it a little hard to read.  I was hoping for it to not have to run `_getLibraryObj` too often.

**Question:** How would you rewrite `this.item()` to be short and sweet *(DRY and readable)*?

**EDIT:-** From alex's post I realised I left out one constraint: If the item isn't in the library object then it might need to `_getLibraryObj()` again as the data may have changed

**Solution:-** I ended up using [@Alex Nolan](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/users/6301)'s fifth example *(with `||` instead of `&&` I find it easier to read.)*:

```
this.item = function(item)
{
    if(!this.obj || !item in this.obj)
    {
        this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();
    }

    return this.obj[item] || null;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Another downfall of your `this.item()` function is that if `item` isn't in `this.obj`, `this._getLibraryObj()` will be called every time.

Try

```
this.item = function(item) {
    if (this.obj) {
        return this.obj[item] || null;
    } else {
        this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();
        return this.item(item);
    }
};
```

Or if you want it even more minimal:

```
this.item = function(item) {
    if (this.obj) 
        return this.obj[item] || null;

    this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();
    return this.item(item);
};
```

If you switch up the statements a little bit you get the most readable IMHO:

```
this.item = function(item) {
    if (!this.obj) 
        this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();

    return this.obj[item] || null;
};
```

One final way to do it would be to do:

```
this.item = function(item) {
    this.obj = this.obj || this._getLibraryObj();

    return this.obj[item] || null;
};
```

EDIT:

In light of your comment about needing to re-call getLibraryObj

```
this.item = function(item) {
    if (!(this.obj && item in this.obj))
        this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();

    return this.obj[item] || null;
};
```

or:

```
this.item = function(item) {
    this.obj = this.obj && item in this.obj ? this.obj : this._getLibraryObj();

    return this.obj[item] || null;
};
```

or a one-liner:

```
this.item = function(item) {
    return (this.obj = (this.obj && item in this.obj ? this.obj : this._getLibraryObj()))[item] || null;
};
```

Comment: Sorry I left one thing out. If the item isn't in the library object then it might need to `_getLibraryObj()` again as the data may have changed. I do really like that "final way" Nice and simple ... how could I have not thought of it!?

Comment: I guess I could put an `if(!item in this.obj){ this.obj = this._getLibraryObj();}` or use the second last example and change the if to `if(!this.obj || !item in this.obj)` *(just thought of a one liner: `return item in (this.obj = this.obj || this._getLibraryObj()) ? this.obj[item] : (this.obj = this._getLibraryObj())[item] || null;`)*